# How to set value in JSON post request by fetching value from response of other request in soapUI Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to Groovy scripting, have done get request in groovy script and got JSON response as:

```
{
    Id: 12,
    Cntid: 3,
    MrId: 1257
    Details: [{
            stid: 224
            trqty: 2,
            Soh: 22
        }, {
            stid: 224,
            trqty: 2,
            Soh: 27
        }, {
            stid: 2341,
            trqty: 21,
            Soh: 89
        }
    ]
}
```

From which I got to retrieve data and create a post operation request as:

```
{
    Id: 12,
    Cntid: 3
    Details: [{
            stid: 224
            trqty: 2
        }, {
            stid: 224,
            trqty: 2
        }, {
            stid: 2341,
            trqty: 21
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do the get and post in a Groovy script if you're using soapUI? Is this being done in the context of a soapUI test case?

Comment: I got to automate the scripts and every time I run the request the response is different according to which the post request will also change

Comment: You can still use soapUI test steps for both requests. After you run the initial request, use Groovy to modify the response how you need to, and set that changed payload as the request in the next test step. Your second request can initially have an empty request payload because the Groovy code below will replace it.  Otherwise, just use something like the groovy-wslite library mentioned in the answer to execute your own calls.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to start with valid JSON: you're missing some commas in your payload.

Assuming you just want to remove a couple of attributes from the response, you could use:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// Get the existing response
def newRequest = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( [your JSON string] )

// Remove the unwanted attributes
newRequest.remove('MrId')
newRequest.'Details'.each {
    it.remove('Soh')
}

// Add new attributes
newRequest.put('status' , 'oma');
newRequest.'Details'.each {
    it.put('active','y')
}
```

If you want to persist with Groovy, you can use a library such as https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite to construct and send your next REST request.

But, why not use soapUI to do that:

```
// Get the next test step in a test case and set the request
def secondREST = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("secondREST")
secondREST.httpRequest.requestContent = newRequest

// Run it
secondREST.run(testRunner, context)
```

Comment: Then how will I add extra values in post request payload before sending it as request? Like I want to add status:"oma" and in details I want to add "active" :"y"

Comment: Code updated above. `JsonSlurper` parses text into a data structure of lists and maps so you can use standard methods to add and remove attributes. Have a go and experiment.